# Navigation Issue in Durandal

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, durandal

I'm attempting to use the following structure to implement navigation buttons using ko (2.3.0), requirejs (2.1.9) and durandal (2.0.1):

file named index.cshtml includes:
     div named applicationHost which loads:
        shell.html which includes:
            div to contain header.html, which includes:
                div to contain data.html, which displays summary info relative to the logged-in user
            div to contain nav.html which includes:
                all the  links for navigation.
            div to contain all other views, depending on which route is active

The router is bound to the shell.html (via shell.js), using boilerplate code to create the router:

```
var shell = {
            router: router,
            activate: function () {                    
                router.map(config.routesNLI).buildNavigationModel();
                return router.activate(my.viewToDisplay());
            }
};
return shell;
```

and is bound in shell.html using the standard:

```
<div>
    <!-- ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, afterCompose: router.afterCompose } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

I took out the transition: 'entrance' because I read where that was causing some people problems, but it had no affect in my case.

The config.routesNLI consists of entries using this pattern:

```
{
    route: 'NLIincontext',
    title: 'In Context',
    moduleId: 'viewmodels/NLIincontext',
    hash: '#/NLIincontext',
    nav: true
}
```

My html for loading the nav.html element into shell.html is:

```
<div>
    <!-- ko compose: {view: 'nav' } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

This is based on the pattern used by John Papa in his excellent PluralSight course , 'Single Page Apps JumpStart'.

When the app is run, the display appears correct, and when you hover on a nav link button, you see (as an example):

```
localhost:49690/index.cshtml#/NLIincontext
```

When you click one of the nav buttons, the address bar is changed to:

```
http://localhost:49690/index.cshtml#/NLIincontext
```

No other visible change is seen on the page, however. If you click at the end of the link in the address bar and click enter, the page loads the appropriate view into the div used in shell.html to display the active item of the router.

Also, if you refresh the page, the address in the address bar does not change, but the page will, upon refresh, display the data associated with the address in the address bar.

No activity is shown in the console log window, even though system.debug(true) is included in my main.js file, and no network activity is displayed when I click the button, nor regardless of how many times the button is clicked.

I have tried data-binding to the div in shell.html using various scenarios, such as:

```
<div data-bind="compose: { view: 'nav' }"></div>
```

I've even bound the nav.html element to the viewmodel (nav.js) by returning the router from nav.js and using this type of binding in shell.html:

```
<div data-bind="compose: { model: 'nav' }></div>
```

I have also tried:

```
<div>
    <!-- ko compose: 'viewmodels/nav' -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

along with other variations like view: 'nav', where appropriate, etc.

I have even tried creating a child router and returning the child router, using the same routes as the router, and binding nav.html to the child router, and still no navigation activity occurs.

Different configurations of the above will properly display the nav.html with its nav buttons, but in no configuration does the web page respond by retrieving the view linked to the button.

I'm new to durandaljs, and I know John Papa's video is based on an earlier version of durandaljs than I am currently using (his model was using sammy.js as the router), but I can't get this routing to work.

I did find where someone else was experiencing a similar problem (in Google Groups durandaljs) and he solved his problem using two lines of code in the activate() method of the router (his solution stated, "The issue was jQuery Mobile's navigation framework interfering with the Durandal router. Adding the following lines to the activate method in the my shell.js file solved the issue"):

```
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```

He appeared to be doing almost exactly what I'm trying to do but unfortunately, I get a 'Declarations of property 'mobile' were not found' message when I try to include those lines in my shell.js file (even though I am able to import jQuery as $ via the define signature of the shell.js file):

```
activate: function () {
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    router.map(config.routesNLI).buildNavigationModel();
    return router.activate(my.viewToDisplay());
}
```

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help.

#### RESOLUION

I appear to have some random issues with navigation, but using the recommendation provided by Krzysztof Cieslak, I changed the binding of my router in my third div to read:

```
<!-- ko router: { transition:'entrance' } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

I then got rid of the references to jquery.mobile and now I am able to navigate to various pages. Unfortunately, the text being copied into the address bar is not always consistent; the reloading of view/viewmodels appears to always work when the url is copied as #/login, resulting in something like:

```
http://localhost:12345/index.cshtml#/login
```

At other times, the address bar is missing the '#/', and navigation fails.

It appears I was guilty of using code written to work with sammy.js's router and not with the durandaljs router. I want to thank all of you who responded and hope to someday be in a position where I can return the favor.

Comment: Please add the requirejs.config. Sounds like jquery mobile isn't loaded yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Hope I can comment multiple times as I have more than 500 chars to write. If not, I'll post remainder as an edit, I guess, as I'm new to this. You are absolutely correct. Up until a few mins ago, I didn't even know there WAS a jQuery mobile module, although it makes perfect sense that there would be. I now have renamed jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js to jqm.js in scripts folder and added it to load via @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/vendor") in index.cshtml. Relevant line in requirejs.config is 'jqm': '../scripts/jqm' & I pass in to shell.js (where router loads) using (define(['jqm'

Comment: Now, I have IntelliSense which is recognizing linkBindingEnabled as a method now. The screen loads and displays properly, but when I click a link button, I get an error which states, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined" and references jqm.js:5136.

Comment: Does it make sense that you would have to 'add' jquery.mobile in order to get around a conflict between the mobile router and the durandal router? As mentioned above, I had no reference to mobile, I just found a link on Google Groups durandal where a poster said his problem was solved by adding those two lines of code to his solution.

Comment: here's that link, in case you're interested: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/durandaljs/3dQlPDLNezU

Answer (score 1):

**Shell.html bindings**

I am little bit confused as You only show us static binding to `nav.html` view and than You say that everything is rendering correctly before navigation. As far as I know Your `shell.html` should look like:

```
<div>
    <header>
        <!--ko  compose: {view: 'nav'} --><!--/ko-->
    </header>
        <div>
            <section id="content" class="main">
                <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance'}--><!--/ko-->
            </section>
        </div>
</div>
```

Where first binding is static `nav.html` binding and second one is dynamic view binding based on router.

**Durandal & jQuery Mobile**

As You have written there is a problem with interference between jQuery Mobile and Durandal routers. Simples way of solving it is editing global jQuery Mobile settings in file `jqm-config.js` ( it's in jQuery Mobile directory) so it looks like:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
        console.log("### Config loaded...");
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;

        $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 100;

        $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is my shell.html:
<div>
    <!-- ko compose: 'viewmodels/header' -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<div>
    <!-- ko compose: {view: 'nav' } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<div>
    <!-- ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, afterCompose: router.afterCompose } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

The first div is for summary info re: logged-in user. The second div is for navigation and the third div is for data display based on which item is active in the router. I have tried static loading of the nav.html and various forms of binding to a nav.js file.

Comment: A couple of different formats work (data-bind="....", as well as <!-- ko compose...), but none of them do anything more than apply the correct address to the address bar - nothing else happens. 

I think my shell.js does follow the pattern you indicate (except I'm using ko compose instead of ko router (I'm taking code from John Papa's tutorial on PluralSight), although durandaljs web site uses your suggestion (and I believe Mr. Papa was using sammy.js with an older version of durandal).  I'm about to try your recommendation and will report back with results shortly, I hope.

Comment: Please see comments to RainerAtSprint above, as I was not previously using jquery.mobile. It doesn't make sense to me that you would have to add jquery.mobile just for the purpose of simply adding the two lines of code to the activate function which one user said was necessary for him, in order to get his app to navigate correctly. I assume he was already using jquery.mobile, but I wasn't and couldn't get past the error messages related to his two lines of code, which he said fixed his problem, without adding jquery.mobile to my project.

Comment: Now, I get an error saying that jquery.mobile is getting an undefined object. I think it all has to do with my routing not being correct, but I don't see a problem with that. I'll provide an update when I have something to report. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you bundling all your js files into 1 file? This sounds like js files being loaded out of order.

Comment: Yes Sir. I am. Here's my sequence (including the jquery.mobile file being loaded as jqm):

Comment: Yes Sir. I am. Here's my sequence (including the jquery.mobile file being loaded as jqm): jquery-2.0.3.min.js, jqm.js, knockout-2.3.0.js, koExternalTemplateEngine_all.js, knockout-delegatedEvents.js, bootstrap.min.js", moment.min.js, Q.js, breeze.debug.js, toastr.js. Can you see any that are out of order, or can you suggest a source where I can see what the sequence should be, or do I need to search through all the dependencies? Thanks for replying!